# How to xLookup values in different columns to check which one is duplicated

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do a xLookup on emails in different columns to check which one is duplicated.

The idea is to lookup an email in one column.
If it doesn't exist then move on to lookup in another column.

*For example*,
if the email is found in A:A then return the said value,
if not found then lookup in B:B and so on.

```
=XLOOKUP(D2,A:A,A:A,XLOOKUP(D2,B:B,B:B,XLOOKUP(D2,C:C,C:C,"",0,1)))
```

The native formula
[image]

I am looking for ways to loop it for each column.

I tried alternatives such as Match function but failed to loop it.

Comment: Why not use Find across the entire set of columns?

Comment: haven't thought about that, because i was sticking with what I am used to in normal excel. How do you propose doing this with Find?

Answer (score 1):

In response to your comment - perhaps something similar to this

```
Sub FindAThing()

    Dim emailAddress As String: emailAddress = "joe.bloggs@email.com"
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B:M")

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim lr As String
    lr = rg.Cells.Find(What:=emailAddress _
                    , Lookat:=xlWhole _
                    , LookIn:=xlValues _
                    , searchorder:=xlByColumns _
                    , searchdirection:=xlNext).Address
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        MsgBox "unable to find email address"
    Else
        MsgBox "Found email in cell " & lr
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a UDF.
Use on a worksheet as `=FindEmail(D2,$A$5:$D$26)`

```
Public Function FindEmail(EmailAddress As String, SearchRange As Range) As Variant

    'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.Volatile
    'A volatile function must be recalculated whenever calculation occurs in any cells on the worksheet.
    'A nonvolatile function is recalculated only when the input variables change.
    Application.Volatile False

    'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find
    Dim rFind As Range
    With SearchRange
        Set rFind = .Find(EmailAddress, .Cells(1, 1), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext, False)
        If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
            FindEmail = rFind
            'or FindEmail = rFind.Address to return the address.
            'or FindEmail = rfind.Row to return the row.  
            'or FindEmail = rfind.Offset(,1) to return the next column across.  
            'or FindEmail = rFind.Font.Name to return the name of the font being used.
        Else
            'Return #N/A if value not found - function must return Variant for this.
            FindEmail = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        End If
    End With
    
End Function
```